# SQL Server : using table function in stored procedure

Tags: c#, sql-server, stored-procedures

I have function for combobox.

```
ALTER FUNCTION [FN.USERNew]
(   
    @USER_ID INT 
)
RETURNS TABLE 
AS
RETURN 
(
Select  [USER_NAME] , username_Id  From USER
WHERE USER_ID=@USER_ID
)
GO
```

I try to use above function in my stored procedure like below.

However, I get an error

> Cannot Find either column"dbo" or the user -defined function or aggregate "dbo.FN.USERNew", or name is ambigous."

```
ALTER PROCEDURE DBO.[MY_STORED_PROCEDURE]
(
    @USER_ID INT,
    @PRODUCT_ID INT
)
AS
BEGIN  
SELECT 

PRODUCT_ID,
PRODUCT_NAME

DBO.FN.USERNew(USER_ID) AS PROBLEMHERE

FROM PRODUCT_TABLE
WHERE PRODUCT_ID=@PRODUCT_ID 
END
```

So why i can not use my function in my stored procedure ?

Comment: Logically you are adding a Table to the column List which is impossible.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to continue to quote the name using `[]` or `""` because `.` is used to separate name parts:

```
ALTER PROCEDURE DBO.[MY_STORED_PROCEDURE]
(
    @USER_ID INT,
    @PRODUCT_ID INT
)
AS
BEGIN  
SELECT 

PRODUCT_ID,
PRODUCT_NAME

DBO.[FN.USERNew](USER_ID) AS PROBLEMHERE

FROM PRODUCT_TABLE
WHERE PRODUCT_ID=@PRODUCT_ID 
END
```

See [Database Identifiers](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms175874.aspx).

---

However, this is a table valued function - which would more normally be used in the `FROM` clause (possibly via [`APPLY`](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms175156%28v=sql.105%29.aspx)) - I'm not sure that SQL Server will let you use it in the `SELECT` clause since it can return *multiple* columns and rows. I think you may want:

```
ALTER PROCEDURE DBO.[MY_STORED_PROCEDURE]
(
    @USER_ID INT,
    @PRODUCT_ID INT
)
AS
BEGIN  
SELECT 

PRODUCT_ID,
PRODUCT_NAME

ft.* AS PROBLEMHERE

FROM PRODUCT_TABLE pt
    CROSS APPLY DBO.[FN.USERNew](pt.USER_ID) ft
WHERE pt.PRODUCT_ID=@PRODUCT_ID 
END
```

Comment: if you have noticed his function is returning a table which cannot be catch in one column

Comment: @Dhaval - there are two issues - the first I noticed is that they need to quote the name - so that part of the answer was correct but not sufficient to completely fix the query. I then realised that it was a TVF so I've added more information in the second part including a guess at what they wanted.

Comment: i have  given down vote before your edit so i have removed it now

Comment: @user2869820 - have you seen the second part of my answer? Also, it should at least have given a *different* error message - when people are trying to help you out (and don't have your tables/data), don't just sat that suggested fixes "don't work" - also indicate anything that has changed since the original question.

Comment: OP: Why do you create a function to select users from its table? And how does user related to products?

Comment: what is pt and ft there ?

Comment: `pt` and `ft` are aliases I've introduced that refer (respectively) to the `PRODUCT_TABLE` and the result of applying your function - aliases allow you to refer to columns in tables or result sets without having to fully specify the entire table name again. The aliases are introduced in the `FROM` clause, after the object name.